# Understand sed function call in a makefile

Tags: c, sed, makefile

I came across the following makefile in a software:

```
CFLAGS = -O6 -g -Wall
CC     = gcc
VPATH  = ./code

LIB_MOD    = common arith inout log
valid_MOD  = valid $(LIB_MOD)
xporta_MOD = porta four_mot portsort largecalc mp $(LIB_MOD)
ALL_MOD    = $(valid_MOD) $(xporta_MOD)

all: xporta valid

valid: $(valid_MOD:%=%.d) $(valid_MOD:%=%.o) 
    $(CC) -o bin/$@ $(valid_MOD:%=%.o)

xporta: $(xporta_MOD:%=%.d) $(xporta_MOD:%=%.o) 
    $(CC) -o bin/$@ $(xporta_MOD:%=%.o)

clean:
    rm -f *.o bin/xporta bin/valid

%.d: %.c
    $(SHELL) -ec 'gcc -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< \
        | sed '\''s/\($*\)\.o[ :]*/\1.o $@ : /g'\'' > $@; \
        [ -s $@ ] || rm -f $@'

include $(ALL_MOD:%=%.d)
```

While I am able to understand the other parts of it, I am unable to understand what the following line does towards the bottom of the makefile:

`| sed '\''s/\($*\)\.o[ :]*/\1.o $@ : /g'\'' > $@; \ [ -s $@ ] || rm -f $@'`

What does this expand to and what is the equivalent syntax without the `sed` function call?

This is an old software written in C and I am trying to rewrite the makefile into a format that is more verbose so that I can understand what is going on.

This is a cross post from /r/c_programming I made where I could not get a specific answer.

Comment: `| sed '\''s/\($*\)\.o[ :]*/\1.o $@ : /g'\'' > $@; \ [ -s $@ ] || rm -f $@'` is 2 lines in your makefile and `;`s or unescaped newlines separate commands in shell. So you're asking about 2 separate commands `| sed '\''s/\($*\)\.o[ :]*/\1.o $@ : /g'\'' > $@` which is the `gcc` command output piped to `sed` and then separately `[ -s $@ ] || rm -f $@'` which is a test that says "if a file named based on the triggered makefile target does not exist or is non empty then remove it if it exists" (yes, it makes no sense and wouldn't work robustly even if it did).

Comment: You asked for help to "Understand sed function call in a makefile" and you got answers about that, ask a new question if you need more help on the rest of that code in your question but I hesitate to guess what they actually meant that code to do (there are at least a couple of possibilities that might make sense but "test if a file exists and is non-empty and if not then remove it if it exists" is not one of them!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual `sed` command is:

```
sed 's/\($*\)\.o[ :]*/\1.o $@ : /g'
```

`'\''` is needed because this is inside the argument to `$(SHELL) -ec`, which is a single-quoted string; it terminates that quote, adds a literal quote, then continues the quoted string.

`$*` and `$@` are [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) that get replaced by `make`.

- `$*` is replaced with the stem of the rule, which is the part of the filename that matched `%` in the rule.
- `$@` is replace with the target of the pattern.

So if the rule is being used to create `foo.d`, the stem is `foo` and the target is `foo.d`. Therefore, the `sed` command becomes

```
sed 's/\(foo\)\.o[ :]*/\1.o foo.d : /g'
```

This basically finds any instances of `foo.o :` in the output of `gcc -MM $<` and inserts `foo.d` between `foo.o` and `:`.

`gcc -MM` is used to create a file containing makefile rules describing all the preprocessor dependencies in the C file. This adds a corresponding `.d` file to any `.o` targets that it generates.

Answer (score 2):

First, `$*` is replaced by the part of the file name that matches the `%`; while `$@` is replaced by the target of the rule (i.e. the `.c` file).

The whole thing is in parentheses as a parameter to `$(SHELL)`. What the shell sees a bit simpler:

```
sed 's/\($*\)\.o[ :]*/\1.o $@ : /g'
```

(with both `$*` and `$@` already replaced). This replaces a (potentially empty) string of spaces and colons after `$*.o` by `$@ :`  (again, with the already replaced `$*` and `$@`).